# Dash App Table links are not clickable - Python Web app issue

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

Dash App Table Not allowing links to be clickable. They appear to be clickable links when I hover my mouse over the title but do not do anything when I click on them.

The following is a function I am using to build the the table:

```
def build_rows(images,titles,author,category,price,link):
    """
    builds a table body. All parameters expect a list type
    """
    rows = []
    for x in range(len(titles)):
        rows.append(html.Tr([html.Img(src=images[x], height="100px"), 
                            html.Td(dcc.Link(titles[x], href=link[x])), # <--- This the problem 
                            html.Td(author[x]), 
                            html.Td(category[x]), 
                            html.Td(price[x]), 
                            html.Td(link[x])]))

    table_body = [html.Tbody(rows)]
    return table_body
```

Thank you for your help. 
NOTE: I always upvote and select a correct answer when applicable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a regular anchor tag with an href, then you want to use `html.A` (ie `import dash_html_components as html`) rather than `dcc.Link`.

The `dcc.Link` component is for use with the `dcc.Location` component, and allows to to create single page applications, by hooking up a callback function to the value of the current URL, returning different layout fragments into a specific container element. If this is what you're trying to do, see the [docs](https://dash.plot.ly/urls) on how to use the `Location` component.